# swift Cannot invoke 'xxx' with an argument list of type '(object: Encodable)'

Tags: swift4

I got an error of `Cannot invoke 'encodeTest' with an argument list of type '(object: Encodable)'`, when i invoke the func like test2 with code below.

It's the code :

```
//test func
func encodeTest<T>(object: T) where T: Encodable {
    // The object should be AnyObject which conforms to Encodable.
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let _ = try? encoder.encode(object) {
        print("encode success.")
        // I need fix the json here.
    }
}

class Test: Encodable {
    var a = "a"
    var b = "b"
}

//test1
var t: Test?
t = Test()
// it is ok.
encodeTest(object: t)


//test2
if let tf = t as Encodable? {
    // Cannot invoke 'encodeTest' with an argument list of type '(object: Encodable)'
    encodeTest(object: tf)
}
```

It's failed to invoke `encodeTest(object: tf)`, how to fix it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `Encodable` protocol doesn't have a declaration of a method `encodeTest(object:`

Comment: It's a method i writed to test. There is a parameter of `object` which conforms to `Encodable`.

Comment: `tf` must be a concrete static type which conforms to `Encodable`. A protocol can not conform to itself.

Comment: Can `tf` be an `AnyObject` here? I try to make the `tf` be an `AnyObject`, and it conforms to `Encodable`.

Comment: No, `Any(Object)` is not a static type.

Comment: So , i should make a basic class of `object`, which conforms to `Encodable`. I get it, Than you!!